# how to use this web service in delphi

Tags: delphi

i have link for use web service.
http://smartcard.rmto.ir:7003/i/web_service/PKG_WEB_SERVICES.xml

and i use this code in delphi,but it is not work.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);    
 var
  d : PKG_WEB_SERVICESPortType;
begin
Memo1.Lines.Clear;
d := GetPKG_WEB_SERVICESPortType(true,'http://smartcard.rmto.ir:7003/i/web_service/PKG_WEB_SERVICES.xml',nil);
Memo1.Lines.Text := d.GET_DRIVER_BY_SHC(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

web service
username:tr_web_service
password:tr_web_service123

thanks

Comment: Please don't ever describe a problem with "It doesn't work". You must be precise about what you expect to happen and what does happen.

Comment: I do not know how should I send a username and password for the web service.

Comment: Not in comments. Please edit the question to have all details.

Comment: Why would you share your credentials with the world to see?

Answer (score 0):

You need read some information about SOAP. See [SOAP in Delphi](https://www.google.com/search?q=soap%20in%20delphi&rct=j&gws_rd=cr,ssl). Try get WSDL file.